# Call AJAX callback on page load

Tags: 8, ajax, page-controller

I've been reading the whole day but I cannot find a complete example for a basic AJAX call on load page.

I followed this [tutorial](http://mike-miles.com/blog/creating-ajax-callback-commands-drupal-8): and this [example](https://github.com/mikemiles86/reveal.js/tree/midcamp-d8ajax/examples/drupal8/remove_example):

I was able to register the callback, controller and commands but the only way to trigger the ajax call is creating a link and is triggered on click event (as the example does)

```
<a class="use-ajax" href="/ajax/nojs/ajaxload">XXX</a>
```

I need to trigger that ajax call but when the page is loaded, is there any way?

Thanks

Comment: Please do not keep adding Drupal 8 in the title. There is already an 8 tag on the question.

Comment: ops, sorry i'm a bit new to stack, in any case, is not better to make it more searchable on google?

Comment: Stack exchange already appends the version number to the page title: `8 - Call AJAX callback on page load - Drupal Answers`

Comment: sound and clear!

Answer (score 5):

Thought I would share this as a slightly more complete solution, this would be your full javascript file:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myModuleName = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      // I am doing a find() but you can do a once() or whatever you like :-)
      $('#element', context).find('.sub-element').each(function () {
        // Do your thing here
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Remember that the context returned on ajax event is the element being replaced, and should match your '#element', if it is inside the element being replaced it is not going to fire.

If you put a watch on the `$('#element', context).find...` line in your browser inspector you will see the different contexts being fired.

Answer (score 4):

Funny how those tutorials did not mention [Drupal behaviors](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview), which will trigger once the page is loaded. [This is a good tutorial on them (Drupal 7, but same principles apply)](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/understanding-javascript-behaviors-in-drupal).

Basically all you should do is call your callback function from a behavior to get the same effect as jQuery's document ready callbacks.

```
Drupal.behaviors.myModule = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    // Call callback here.
  }
};
```

And while you are at it, I recommend reading up on behaviors as they help to streamline your javascripts and keeps them in closed scopes.

Comment: @ManuelRodriguez I have updated the documentation to a Drupal 8 link, but not much has changed between 7 and 8.

Comment: I have implemented this and indeed it acts as onload, so that's something achieved, thanks! but the second question is, how do i "call" my ajax callback? I have no idea how to do that, neither I found anything on internet.
My link that triggers the ajax load looks like:

    `<a class="use-ajax" href="/ajax/nojs/xxxload">Remove Image</a>`

But I don't know how to get same behaviour just on the on load (and i don't want to make a click onload to that link... )

Comment: That is basic jquery (not specific to Drupal, hence of topic here), but you probably want to call the url with [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or the short hand [`jQuery.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).

Comment: oh Neograph734 thanks, i was totally obfuscate with the AJAX logic I couldn't see the simplest part :D