# Run JavaScript after Ajax Call

Tags: 8, forms, javascript

I have a form file:

```
namespace Drupal\h_scheduler\Form;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

class DayAddEntries extends FormBase {

  public counter = 0;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'hs_day_add_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form_state->setCached(FALSE);

    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'h_scheduler/form_actions';

    /*...More fields....*/

    /* Special */
    $form['specials'] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#tree' => TRUE,
      '#title' => t('Specials'),
      '#prefix' => '<div id="specials">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );

    if ($this->counter) {
      for ($i = 1; $i <= $this->counter; $i++) {
        $form['specials']['special'.$i] = array(
          '#type' => 'fieldset',
          '#title' => t('Special ') . $i,
          '#tree' => TRUE,
        );
        $form['specials']['special'.$i]['field'] = array(
          '#type' => 'number',
          '#title' => t('Every'),
          '#title_display' => 'before',
        );
        $form['specials']['special'.$i]['field'] = array(
          '#type' => 'textfield',
          '#title' => t('Prefix'),
          '#title_display' => 'after',
        );
      }
    }
    $form['specials']['operations']['#type'] = 'actions';
    $form['specials']['operations']['add_special'] = array(
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => $this->t('Add special'),
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => '::ajaxAddSpecial',
        'wrapper' => 'specials',
      ),
    );

    /* Not working */
    $form['specials']['operations']['remove_special'] = array(
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => $this->t('Remove special'),
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => '::ajaxRemoveSpecial',
        'wrapper' => 'specials',
      ),
    );

    /* Submit */
    $form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
    $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Save'),
      '#button_type' => 'primary',
    );

    $this->counter++;

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * Increments the number of specials to have
   */
  public function ajaxAddSpecial($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form['specials'];
  }

  /**
   * Decrements the number of specials to have
   */
  public function ajaxRemoveSpecial($form, $form_state) {
    $this->counter -= 2;
    return $form['specials'];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    /* Do stuff */

  }
}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#edit-specials .fieldset-wrapper .fieldset-wrapper, #edit-regular .fieldset-wrapper').addClass('entry-wrapper').each(addStyleClasses);

  function addStyleClasses() {
    console.log('hi');
    $(this).children('.form-item')
      .addClass(function() {
        var regex = /form-item-\S+-(\S+)/;
        return regex.exec($(this).attr('class'))[1];
      })
      .not('.every').wrapAll('<div class="item-wrapper">');
  }
```

});

I'm able to add a new "special" item, but when I do it appears wacky.

This is because I've styled the form using a jQuery function that adds classes and wraps elements. However, that function does not run when the `form['specials']` is rebuilt.

My question, how do I run a JS function after an ajax call?

Comment: Can you please post your jQuery code? The problem is likely to be there.

Comment: Use Drupal.behaviors and jquery once in your code and you'll be fine.

Comment: @NoSssweat Added JS. I can confirm that my jQuery code works the on load, but when I rebuild the `form['specials']` the JS doesn't apply to it.

Comment: @IvanJaros Thanks, I'll check it out and get back to you.

Comment: @IvanJaros I solved it using Drupal.behaviors and jquery once! Thanks, and if you'll add an answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: Related: https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/ajax-api/core-ajax-callback-commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has a solution on Stackexchange [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224379/call-ajax-callback-on-page-load/248372#248372) already, but:

This would be your full javascript file:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myModuleName = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      // I am doing a find() but you can do a once() or whatever you like :-)
      $('#element', context).find('.sub-element').each(function () {
        // Do your thing here
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Note on the question's js: I would say when calling a function like your addStyleClasses() it would be more reliable to explicitly pass your target element in the function call than using $(this) in there.